# Genetic algorithm - Feature selection packages in Python

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, data-mining, feature-selection

Can you share some packages in Python which are implemented that I can use for selecting features based on a genetic algorithm?

I did refer to this AUTO-ML [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/genetic-algorithm-only-using-selection) and found out that it is useful but doesn't really do a feature selection and return the best subset.

I am already aware of this `sklearn-genetic`, can you share if you know of any other genetic algorithm package?